# NSMutableData not releasing memory automatically

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, nsdata

I am writing on a iOS program and I have a memory leak. I reproduce it on macOS, which I don't know how to solve it. It is very simple.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        system("top -l 1 | grep LEAK"); // baseline
        NSMutableData* dataobj = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:DATA_SIZE];
        system("top -l 1 | grep LEAK"); // baseline + 8 bytes
        memset([dataobj mutableBytes], 1, DATA_SIZE);
        system("top -l 1 | grep LEAK"); // baseline + DATA_SIZE
        dataobj = nil;
        system("top -l 1 | grep LEAK"); // baseline + DATA_SIZE
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the end, I am expecting memory usage at baseline again, but it is not. Waiting for 10 seconds still the same result. I believe it must be something wrong with my understanding of ARC or `NSData`.

Thank everyone who takes a look at it in advance.

Comment: top is not a tool for detecting memory leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating your data with:

```
NSMutableData* dataobj = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:DATA_SIZE];
```

Due to the [Memory Management Policy](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) you're not an owner of this object, and it is placed in the Autorelease Pool. Since you're code is completely embedded in an `@autoreleasepool { ... }`, it can't detect a deallocation of the data, because it is kept by this pool.

You're code doesn't contain a leak, and the operating system is responsible for the cleaning. This generally makes the success of your experiment very questionable. Finally, I would like to endorse Amin's comment: You're using the wrong methods. You should use Instruments instead.

Comment: Thank you for taking time writing the answer! I used Xcode to show memory hierarchy graph, indeed, autorelease pool still holds the reference to NSConcreteData after set to nil. Set a breakpoint outside the pool, reference goes away, but it still takes up memory (which I guess as you said, it's OS's job for the cleaning). As my program is very strict with memory usage, I am switching to C style malloc/free, which works as I expected.